# Scanner Keeps Asking For Credentials Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, password, scanner

Any time I invoke my scanner program, the program almost locks (several times I often get the Force Quit / Wait prompt) and after several seconds, I am prompted for my login credentials. After a few more seconds, I can scan. It is a network scanner.

Have tried several different things:

1 - Adding my username to the scanner group 2 - Edited the visudo file and allowed my user to be exempted from passwording. 3 - All updating etc.

UPDATE: interesting twist - if I cancel out of the credential request, it still finds the scanner and allows me to use the scanner.

Comment: What is the scanner program? You tell us your are using a scanner program and then do not say what it is.

Comment: It is a brother scanner MFC-L2750DW. I use the linux driver package provided by them. And the printer works perfectly.

Comment: If it is their software it would seem its a question you need to ask them.

Comment: I have several computers running this brother installation on machines with <22.04 versions on it that don't ask for the credentials. I actually use the same zip file on all machines.